# Improve spacy lemmatization with bigrams, proper nouns, and plurals?

Tags: python, nlp, gensim, spacy

In python, I'm building ngrams with gensim and passing the words into spacy for lemmatization. I'm finding that spacy is not working very well as it's keeping many words as plurals that shouldn't be.

It looks like this is mostly happening when it's mistakenly tagging nouns as proper nouns.

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en', disable=['parser','ner'])

doc = nlp(u"bed_bugs bed bug beds bedbug bugs bed_bug nymph nymphs nintendo")

for token in doc:
    print("original: {}, Lemma: {}, POS: {}".format(token, token.lemma_, token.pos_))
```

output:

```
original: bed_bugs, Lemma: bed_bugs, POS: PROPN
original: bed, Lemma: bed, POS: NOUN
original: bug, Lemma: bug, POS: NOUN
original: beds, Lemma: bed, POS: VERB
original: bedbug, Lemma: bedbug, POS: PROPN
original: bugs, Lemma: bugs, POS: PROPN
original: bed_bug, Lemma: bed_bug, POS: X
original: nymph, Lemma: nymph, POS: PROPN
original: nymphs, Lemma: nymphs, POS: PROPN
original: nintendo, Lemma: nintendo, POS: PROPN
```

My preferred output would have these changes -

```
bed_bugs -> bed_bug
nymphs -> nymph
bugs -> bug
```

Is there a way to accomplish this with spacy or some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

Spacy's v2.2 models have some changes to try to make them less sensitive to capitalization so they can work better on informal texts like social media texts, but one of the side effects is that they have trouble differentiating common vs. proper nouns if they don't have any context. They will perform much better with some natural language context, like "I saw bedbugs in my neighbor's apartment."

If you know that all your words are common nouns in advance, you can also call the lemmatizer directly like this for an individual word:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
lemmatizer = nlp.Defaults.create_lemmatizer()
lemmatizer("bedbugs", "NOUN") # ['bedbug']
```